# How to concatenate string with unichar in python 2.7?

Tags: string, unicode, ipython, unichar

How to concatenate `str` with `unichr` in python 2.7 in `Jupyter IPython`?
As I've tried following.

```
string = 'blah blah'
unicode_char = unichr(169)
end_str = string + unicode_char
end_str
```

would throw `u'blah blah\xa9'` where I want to display like `blah blah©`.

Comment: The `u` indicates that it is unicode.  (In py3 you have to add an explicit `decode` to the bytestring first).

Comment: If you want to display it correctly, `print` it; otherwise, you get a debug representation.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2 the strings are bytes and when you add a byte out of ASCII scope the string represents it as \x and a hexadecimal code.
But if you call your unicode string from print it will show de unicode caracter, in your case a copyright symbol.

```
print end_str
```